# Kernel - less options, more ram usage. Weird

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

#### Context

I compiled a new kernel 3.14.

I link the configurations below.

The one compiled by the Debian team ends up eating less memory whereas I disabled a bunch of options on my custom one.

If someone experimented could give me a tip, it is more than welcome.

It is a apple core 2 duo, 64 bits. Debian.

Kernel 3.12
http://pastebin.com/63ag59Fq

Custom 3.14
http://pastebin.com/u4i9UV3N

The 3.14's config file is much smaller.

#### Question

Isn't it strange ?

Are there some options I should activate to reduce the ram usage ?